# Save the screenshot of the scene locally in unity

Tags: unity, c#

I have a unity project which contain a button in the scene. I have loaded a terrain also into the scene. When I run the project, the terrain and the button will be shown. When I click on the button, a screenshot should be taken saved to the device.

How can I do that in unity?

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.CaptureScreenshot.html

You can use this method to capture the screen buffer at normal or scaled sizes. Give it a file path to save to, and it'll be saved there. Put this in your button press/click event( can't tell if you mean an in game button, or UI )